# Replace a date string in sed with the ouput of a custom function with arguments

Tags: date, sed, unix-timestamp, command-substitution

I have a bash script which echos out an html file like
this `./foo.sh > out.html` In the html there are timestamps in the
following format `2019-02-24T17:02:19Z`.

I wrote a function to
convert the time stamp to the time delta between the timestamp
and now.

```
my_uptime(){
    START=$(date -d "$1" "+%s")
    NOW=$(date "+%s")
    STD=$(echo "($NOW-$START)/3600" | bc)
    MIN=$(echo "(($NOW-$START)/60)%60" | bc)
    echo "Uptime $STD h $MIN min"
}
```

Now I want to replace the timestamp with the output of `my_uptime`
directly in the stream. I tried this:

```
echo "<p>some html</p>
2019-02-24T17:02:19Z
<p>some more html</p>" | sed -r "s/[0-9\-]+T[0-9:]+Z/$(my_uptime \0)/"
```

This fails because the command substitution doesn't recognize the
back reference and puts in a literal `0`. Is there another way to
achieve this? Preferably directly in the stream.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew same problem. This basically outputs my local time because it calls `my_uptime 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... | sed -r "s/[0-9\-]+T[0-9:]+Z/$(my_uptime \0)/"
```

This code is attempting to pass the matched value from sed's `s///` into the shell function. However, `$(...)` is expanded before sed even sees it.

Using sed is probably not appropriate here.

Here's a perl replacement that effectively combines your shell function and sed:

```
... | perl -ple '
    if (/([0-9-]+T[0-9:]+Z)/) {
        $s = `date -d "$1" +%s`;
        $n = time;
        $h = int(($n-$s)/3600);
        $m = int(($n-$s)/60)%60;
        $_ = "Uptime $h h $m min";
    }'
```

You could probably do something similar in awk.